One of the Multiple Columns Primary Key is Inferred from another because of ORDER BY request
Context
I have a table T with its primary key containing multiple columns:
A, B, C, D
Use Cases
This table may contains millions of rows.
And there are two constraints:

Reading fast using an ORDER BY on (A, B, C, D)  in this order
INSERTING as fast as possible millions of rows  within a batch

Problem
For a specific value of C, there will always be the same value of B.
Column B can be inferred from column C.
So it seems that column B should not be part of the primary key.
But it seems it can help the ORDER-BY-GET request.
Do you think I should remove column B from the primary key?

What else does the query that has the ORDER BY do? You might need another index for that query anyway, which would resolve the conflict.

You can remove column B from index; and create a covering index for that specific order by query. The additional index will affect insert performance though. Also, does B really belong to that table if it depends on C?

I think you should separate the logical and physical aspects.

From the point of view of the logical model:

A candidate key (or minimal superkey) is a superkey that can't be
reduced to a simpler superkey by removing an attribute.

Because a primary key is a chosen candidate key, you should exclude the inferred attributes.

From the physical model perspective, I would start benchmarking solutions in terms of your use cases. And if necessary, I would solve them using such means as indexes.

P.S. In general, your requirements to read fast and to insert fast are competing.
